# How to use admin table theme with multistep form?

Tags: users

I have 1000 records of users with name and checkbox. I want to show the list of users in table theme. I have use

```
theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
```

But how to use it with multistep form. Please find the below code.

```
function getForm() {
$form = array();
$step1 = array();

drupal_add_js("
function checkUncheckAll(theElement){
  var theForm = theElement.form, z = 0;
  for(z=0; z<theForm.length;z++){
    if(theForm[z].type == 'checkbox' && theForm[z].name != 'checkall'){
      theForm[z].checked = theElement.checked;
    }
  }
}", 'inline');

$step1['user'] = array(
   '#type' => 'container',
   '#tree' => TRUE,
   '#prefix' => '<div id="user">',
   '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
$results = db_query("SELECT* FROM {user_token} ut LEFT JOIN {users} u ON u.uid= ut.uid where u.status=1 and u.uid!=0 group by ut.uid ")->fetchAll();

foreach($results as $k=>$result)
{
  $user[$result->uid] = $result->name;
    $defaults = array_keys($user);
}

 $step1['checkall'] = array(
 '#type' => 'checkbox',
 '#title' => t('Select / Unselect all'),
 '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'checkUncheckAll(this);'),
 '#weight' => -1,
 );

 $step1['user'] = array(
 '#type' => 'checkboxes',
 '#title' => t('Send message to listed users'),
 '#options' => $user,
 //'#default_value' => $defaults,
 '#attributes' => array('class' => array('check_notify_user'))
 );

 $step1['submit']=array(
     '#type'=>'submit',
     '#value'=>t('Next')
 );


$form[] = $step1;

$step2['message'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => 'Message',
  '#description' => t('No more than 250 words please!'),
  '#wysiwyg' => false,
  '#attributes' => array('maxlength' => 250),
);

$step2['prev'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Previous'),
  '#name' => 'prev',
  '#submit' => array('custom_previous_submit'),
);

$step2['submit']=array(
    '#type'=>'submit',
    '#value'=>t('Submit')
  );

$form[] = $step2;

return $form;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to do the multi-step form. For the table, you can use Drupal's table theme function. If the table contains only markup, you can do something like this:

```
$form['table'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#rows' => $rows,    
  '#empty' => 'Empty List - No Entries',
  '#header' => $header,
);
```

or

```
$form['table'] = array ('#value' => theme('table', $headers, $rows));
```

You can use this in multistep form also.

If the table contains actual form elements (such as selects, textfields, etc.), you can wrap them in a form element that calls a theme function, like so:

```
$form['table'] = array ('#theme' => 'output_table');

$form['table']['element_1'] = array (...);
$form['table']['element_2'] = array (...);
```

Within 'theme_output_table', generate your $headers and $rows to feed to 'theme_table' by calling 'drupal_render' on the relevant form elements that are children of $form['table'].